# Is a cross product boundary condition equivalent to a Dirichlet b.c.?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-fields, cross-product, elliptic-equations

Suppose that $E=\nabla u + \nabla \times \Psi$ is an electric field, satisfying $$E \times n=0 \textrm{ on }\partial \Omega$$ and
$$
\textrm{div} ( \varepsilon E +J )=0 \textrm{ in } \Omega,
$$
where $\Omega$ is a smooth domain in $\mathbb R^3$ and $J$ is a smooth vector valued function (a current).

Suppose that the (smooth) vector potential $\Psi$ is known. Then it becomes an elliptic PDE in $\nabla u$, namely, setting $f=\textrm{div} ( \varepsilon \nabla \times \Psi + J)$,
and $g= - \nabla\times \Psi \times n $ ,

$$-\textrm{div} ( \varepsilon \nabla u)= f \textrm{ in } \Omega, \quad \nabla u \times n = g \textrm{ on } \partial\Omega.$$

The boundary condition puzzles me a bit, as it isn't a usual Neumann or Dirichlet one. It feels like Dirichlet up to a constant, namely I am tempted to think that in fact
$$
\nabla u \times n = g \textrm{ on } \partial\Omega  \Leftrightarrow u = G \textrm{ on } \partial\Omega, 
$$
up to possibly imposing something on an integral of $u$. Is it true, and if yes, how is $G$ defined in terms of $g$?

Comment: Under standard definitions, $E = -\nabla u -\partial_t A$. $\nabla\times A$ is $B$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog  I am writing the field as gradient + curl : Helmholtz decomposition if you wish.

Comment: I'd suggest using a different symbol for that then. In the context of electromagnetism, $A$ has a very specific meaning, and it makes your question more confusing to be used in a different way.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Now changed.